# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to make a form login. But when i want to see the result in browser, nothing happen. when i open console, the error is :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . services.js:3

I dont know whats wrong with the code. Anyone can help me please? I'm new in ionic

index :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/constant.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

controller :

```
angular.module('starter')

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS){

});
```

services :

```
angular.module('starter');

.service('AuthService', function($q, $http, API_ENDPOINT) {
    return {

    };
})

.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, AUTH_EVENTS){
    return {

    };
})

.config(function ($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
});
```

app.js :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('outside',{
    url : '/outside',
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl : 'templates/outside.html'
  })
  .state('outside.login',{
    url : '/login',
    templateUrl : 'templates/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginCtrl'
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/outside/login')
})
```

form login :

```
<ion-view view-title="Please Sign in">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
        <button class="button button-full button-clear button-positive" ui-sref="outside.register">Register Now!</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: remove ; from angular.module('starter');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your services remove the ; in the first line.

angular.module('starter');  <--- This one